# Evaluate integral with no elementary antiderivative $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

This is a followup from my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013740/evaluating-an-improper-integral-using-the-comparison-test).

I was asked to determine if the following integral converges or diverges. If the integral converges, I was asked to determine the value.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+x+1} dx $$.

With help from the question I posted above, I managed to figure out my comparison (Thanks!). I definitely know this converges now. How do I find the value though? As far as I can see, this integral has no elementary antiderivative.

This is a standard intermediate calculus class which does do not calculus of residues or anything complicated like that so I'm not how to proceed there.

Wolfram alpha says that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+x+1} dx = 0$$ and that makes a lot of sense! However, I can't find a way to justify what the value should be rigirously.

Can someone help out here?

Comment: Variants of this improper integral (requiring the "trick" given in the answers below) appear in many calculus textbook problem sections.  One version is given in Nahin's _Inside Interesting Integrals_, pp. 14-15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} dx \overset{x\to \frac1x}=- \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1}=-I
=0
$$

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you just did here.

Comment: @FutureMathperson - I used the shorthand for the substitution $t=\frac1x$.

Comment: Ahh thank you! This really helped out :) .

Answer (score 3):

This might help
$$I=  \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+x+1}\,\mathrm dx$$
Substituting, $x=\frac1y$ and hence $\mathrm dx=-\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2}$ we  get
$$I= \int_\infty^0-\frac{\ln(1/y)}{(y^2+y+1)/y^2}\,\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2} $$
$$I = -I$$
$$I = 0$$

Comment: This was very useful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} d x &=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} d x+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} d x \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+x+1} d \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (x)}{x^2+x+1} d x } \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$